# Jquery - Copy name/title/alt tag from input to table

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
<tr class="DataGridAlterItem" align="center">
<td align="center">
    <input id="ctl00_PageBody_grdCustomers_ctl117_rdoCustomerSelect" type="radio" name="rdo_ctl117" value="rdoCustomerSelect" onclick="check(this);" class="radio">
</td>

<div class="myDIV">
This is the related text for div###
</div>
```

What Im trying to accomplish is to have the TD "name" (name="rdo_ctl117") value copied to the DIV in the same row.

The end result would look like this

```
<tr class="DataGridAlterItem" align="center">
<td align="center">
    <input id="ctl00_PageBody_grdCustomers_ctl117_rdoCustomerSelect" type="radio" name="rdo_ctl117" value="rdoCustomerSelect" onclick="check(this);" class="radio">
</td>

<div class=""myDIV name="rdo_ctl117">
This is the related text for div###
</div>
```

Ive tried using clone but it tries to copy the whole input element...i only need the name attribute.

I also tried next, prev, siblings, etc. but it doesnt behave as expected.

```
$('input[name^="rdo_ctl"]').click(function(){
 var tblTitle = $(this).attr('name');
$(this).next().prop('title', tblTitle);
});

$('input[name^="rdo_ctl"]').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('name',name).appendTo('.myDIV', name);
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: _"TD 'name'"_ Don't you mean input name attribute?

Comment: A div without a TD inside a TR inside a table, looks invalid ?

Comment: j08691 - you are correct ... trying to simplify the code for posting my example

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/x2VkU/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr class="DataGridAlterItem" align="center">
        <td align="center">
            <input id="ctl00_PageBody_grdCustomers_ctl117_rdoCustomerSelect" type="radio" name="rdo_ctl117" value="rdoCustomerSelect" class="radio" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="myDIV">This is the related text for div###</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**js**

```
$('input[name^="rdo_ctl"]').click(function () {
    var tblTitle = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).closest('td').next().find('div.myDIV').prop('name', tblTitle);
});
```

Comment: Hi Tushar - its not working for me. No errors, but its not updating the DIV. ANy suggestions?

Comment: @user1028445 post your full table html.Is your site online ?